# Scaling and centring in PCA of compositional data

Tags: r, pca, compositional-data

I am following [this review's](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-38/issue-3/Aitchisons-Compositional-Data-Analysis-40-Years-on-A-Reappraisal/10.1214/22-STS880.short) approach for PCA using compositional data. It involves computing the centred log-ratio (CLR) transformation of the compositional data, and then running PCA on the resulting matrix (a "log-ratio analysis" apparently).

I use `prcomp()` in R for the PCA, and it is not clear to me whether and how I should set the `center` and `scale.` parameters. The dimension of my compositional data is large (over 100 components), and they all have similar magnitudes.

How would one choose whether to centre and scale such data? Thank you

Comment: you most always want to scale and center the data prior to PCA, this put the explanatory variables on equal playing fields so so speak, especially when variable measurement units are of different scales.  The only exception to this general rule is if you have explanatory variables with the same units, ranges and comparable (equal variances)

Comment: As a side note, if you are working with [species] compositional data and you want to do multivariate analysis (PCA is a type of multivariate analysis), you probably want PCoA (Principle Coordinates Analysis) and not a PCA.  NMDS is also good, but it gives imaginary axes (the values of the axes are relative and not real).  In such case, you need to compute a distance matrix from the species composition data (abundance or presence-absence matrix).  See McCune and Grace 2002 Analysis of Ecological Communites for details